Safe selecting non-existent column in SQL (or dbt)
Is there a way of safe selecting a column that doesn't exists in a table without geting "invalid identifier" error? Maybe returning null instead?
Something like this:
select 
    id, 
    non_existant_column as col_name -- return null here instead of rising an error

from table

I tried already a number of SQL (coalesce, ifnull, ...) and dbt (dbt_utils.star, jinja adapter) functions.
I would like to see a simple solution returning null in the column values if the column doesn't exists.

Nope, why would you need this? You do know the columns each table has, right?

The problem is that I use a dbt loop to unionize some 50+ tables. Not all tables have the same columns. I would like for the select from such tables not to brake, and return null or predefined value instead.

Use SELECT id, NULL as col_name FROM table ?

It helps if you ask your question with the main problem you're trying to solve. Unioning multiple tables safely is done easily using dbt-utils/union_relations

There is a PostgreSQL way using JSON, not very nice however.
select 
    jr['id']::integer as id, 
    jr['non_existant_column'] as col_name
from (select to_jsonb(t) jr from the_table t) t;

A typecast would be needed for col_name expression.
In your particular case it would be something like
select
  id, existent_column_a, existent_column_b, ...,
  jr['non_existent_column_a'] as col_name_a,
  jr['non_existent_column_b'] as col_name_b,
  ...
from (select *, to_jsonb(t) jr from the_table t) t;

column_name_x expressions would need to be typecast. You may also prefer JSONB arrow syntax (jr -> 'non_existent_column_a') rather than subscripting.

This is easy to do in DBT:
{%- set columns = dbt_utils.get_filtered_columns_in_relation(from=source('source_name', 'table_name')) -%}

select 
    id,
    {% if 'non_existant_column' in columns -%}
      non_existant_column as col_name
    {% else %}
      NULL as col_name
    {% endif %}
from table

Under the hood, this is doing the same thing as Gerik's answer above. It queries the underlying DB's information schema at compile time to retrieve the column list which you can use to generate your final SQL.

Thanks! I am aware of this but it won't work against ephemeral models. I was hoping I wouldn't need to materialize all models in the destination dw.

Correct. This won't work with ephemeral models. There's no way to do it if you're not willing to change your materialization. It's the same reason why dbt_utils.star() doesn't work on CTEs. Ephemeral models are just inline replacements.

There's a small syntax error here - it needs the closing parenthesis in line 1: {%- set columns = dbt_utils.get_filtered_columns_in_relation(from=source('source_name', 'table_name')) -%}

This is dependent upon the database you're using, but:
In PostgreSQL:
In short, no, when you run a query against a non-existant resource, it will throw an error.  However, there are ways you can work around this.
For example you can run queries against your database to check your schema, however:
A) This has to be run before you run your queries, and
B) I would recommend using a different database engine such as a NoSQL db if you need schema flexibility - schema flexibility is not what relational databases are exactly intended for.
Getting schema information:
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='data_table'

An example query using schema information:
DO $$
DECLARE
    column_exists BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    SELECT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE table_name='data_table' AND column_name='value_column'
    ) INTO column_exists;

    IF column_exists THEN
        EXECUTE 'SELECT name, value_column FROM data_table';
    ELSE
        EXECUTE 'SELECT name, NULL::INT AS value_column FROM data_table';
    END IF;
END $$;


I had this in mind but the thing is I am unionizing 50 ephemeral dbt models (look at them as CTEs in standard SQL). Columns of such models are not written in the information schema or anywhere.

This code doesn't work since DO can't return anything, it returns a void. From the manual: The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void.

@FrankHeikens, these were only meant to be examples of how to work with schema information; they were not intended to be actual solutions.

@Damir: another alternative you could use would be to create a view for each of the tables you're working with which would allow you to set the exact structure you need for the tables before they are queried - not views on the CTEs of course, but the source tables your CTEs would be built from.

@Gerik, both of your suggestions are valid and helpful. I already materialized those models as views and use dbt_utils.star to determine if a column exists. I sure hoped I would avoid such a scenario since it complicates my destination structure.
